# Chrome Ошибка сети

Tags: windows, google-chrome

При скачивании файла через секунд 30 "Ошибка: Ошибка сети"

Всем спасибо, проблема решена удаление папки Temp.

Comment: конкретнее...при скачивание любого файла? или конкретно какого-то..откуда-то?

Comment: любого файла с любого сайта

Comment: `curl`, `ff`, `aria2` тоже не пашут на тех же ссылках?

Comment: другой браузер пробовали? есть отличия? я б кеш прочистил ну и переставил бы брозер )

Comment: Любой браузер, но с того же компа на линуксе всё ок

Comment: curl робит, но файл оказывается повреждённым